# What should the build.gradle contain for Sentry log4j2?

Tags: gradle, makefile, log4j2, sentry, moqui

wondering if you can help.

I'm trying to integrate Sentry into my moqui/Gradle/Java project which uses the log4j2 logger.

Sentry says they support this. However, they do not have a tutorial / example for this.

The closest they have is a Makefile with the following code:

```
# Must have `sentry-cli` installed globally
# Following variable must be passed in
#  SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN

SENTRY_ORG=testorg-az
SENTRY_PROJECT=java-springboot-log4j
VERSION=`sentry-cli releases propose-version`

deploy: setup_release run_jar

setup_release: create_release associate_commits

create_release:
    sentry-cli releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) new -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) $(VERSION)

associate_commits:
    sentry-cli releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) set-commits --auto $(VERSION)

run_jar:
    mvn clean package && \
     java -agentpath:libsentry_agent.dylib -Dsentry.release=$(VERSION) -jar target/sentry-springboot-log4j2-example-0.0.1.jar
```

Does anyone know what the Gradle equivalent should be for my project?